# Delphi - Referencing Components created at Runtime

Tags: delphi, reference, runtime, components

I'm using Delphi 5 and I'm creating a number of panels at runtime, then creating buttons on the panels, obviously again at runtime.  I need to do it this way because I may need to dynamically create more panel/button combinations in the future.

I can do all of this, but I'm at a loss as to how to reference the panels I've created, because I can't find a way to access the panels' component name.   Hunting around the Internet I've found that I can use FindComponent to find the panel components by name, but I still don't know how to use that name, because I can't use a string variable to refer to it - e.g. StringVar := Panel.Name.  I get a type mismatch, TComponentName versus String.

I created the buttons for each panel as I created the panels. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
   With TypeQuery do begin // Create Panels
   First;
   While (not eof) do begin        // create the actual panel
      panelno := FieldByName('Product_type_id').AsInteger;
      pnl := Tpanel.Create(Self);
      pnl.name := FieldByName('PanelName').AsString;
      pnl.color := clInactiveCaption;
      pnl.parent := MainForm;
      pnl.width := 365;
      pnl.Height := 551;
      pnl.left := 434
      pnl.top := 122;
      pnl.caption := '';
      With ButtonQuery do begin
         Close;
         Parameters.parambyname('PanelID').Value := PanelNo;
         Open;
         First;
         While (not eof) and (FieldByName('Product_type_id').AsInteger = PanelNo) do begin    //put the buttons on it.
            btnName := FieldByName('ButtonName').AsString;
            BtnText := FieldByName('ButtonText').AsString;
            BtnGroup := FieldByName('Product_Group_ID').AsString;
            GrpColour := FieldByName('ButtonColour').AsString;
            btn := TColorButton.Create(Self);
            btn.Parent := pnl;
            btn.Name := BtnName;
            Btn.backcolor := HexToTColor(GrpColour);
            btn.Font.Name := 'Arial Narrow';
            btn.Font.Style := [fsBold];
            btn.Font.Size := 10;
            . . .
        end;
        . . .
     end; 
  end;
```

I've read on several forums (including this one) that there is no way to reference the panels by name directly.  I've tried using a component array, but I strike the same problem - I need to refer to the component by its assigned component name.

Okay, I'm not a gun programmer - I've used Delphi for years to create simple programs, but this one is a lot more complex.  I've never worked with runtime component creation before.

Can I use FindComponent to make the panels visible or invisible?   If so, given what I have shown you above, can you give me the approach I should take in baby-steps?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: You can add the components you need references to a TList|Container... and then, use your list|container to access them...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by:
"*I can't use a string variable to refer to it - e.g. StringVar := Panel.Name.*"

Try this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  p: TPanel;
begin
  p := TPanel.Create(Self); // create a TPanel at run-time
  p.Name := 'MyPanel'; // set a unique name
  p.Parent := Self;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  p: TPanel;
  StringVar: string;
begin
  p := FindComponent('MyPanel') as TPanel;
  if Assigned(p) then // p has reference to MyPanel
  begin
    // use that reference
    p.Caption := 'Foo';
    StringVar := p.Name;
    ShowMessage(StringVar);
  end;
end;
```

Or did I miss anything?

Comment: No, you didn't.  It should have been obvious, but it wasn't!  Thanks very much.

Comment: I have a panel inside other panel so I used this way first to find the parent panel and then called FindComponent function from parent panel and that's worked. Thanks.

Comment: I was using TPanel.Create(Application) and it didn't work. It should be .Create(Self). Saved my life, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You're conflating the *component name* with the *variable name*. The Delphi IDE strives to keep those two the same, for IDE-created components, but they're not necessarily equal. You don't have *variable names* because you're creating the components dynamically, and you don't know how many variables you'd need. However, you still have control over the component names: Simply assign the `Name` property of the component, and then you can use it the same way you use any other component names, by calling `FindComponent`. Just make sure the names are unique for each panel instance.

Remember also that the way to deal with variables, when you don't know at compile time how many you'll need, is to use *arrays* or *lists*. You can use plain old arrays, or you can use a more sophisticated data structure like `TComponentList` or `TDictionary`.

Finally, to make it easier to refer to the controls *on* the panels you're creating, you can dispense with the panels and use *frames* instead. You can visually design a `TFrame` in the IDE and give names to the buttons, and at run time, you can instantiate the frame class, and it will automatically create all the buttons for you, just like when you instantiate a form or data module. You only need to give a name to the new frame object, but that object will already have named fields referring to the buttons.

Comment: @Whiler, no, but we don't really need separate questions and answers for every possible Delphi version. It's the same question regardless of version. People can use whatever classes are available to them in the version they happen to be using when they read this answer. Besides, I didn't say it was necessarily the `TDictionary` class that comes with modern Delphi versions; anyone can write a dictionary-like class and use it to store object references.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  Much appreciated.  I'll have a look at TFrames for another app I have in mind ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

There should be no need to create a secondary list of items you created to display on a tForm instance.

AFAIK, whenever you create a new panel that uses a Form or an other Container in place of self

```
  pnl := Tpanel.Create(Self);
```

you don't need to take care of destroying then new pnl, because it is handled by the containing "self" component.

This means that there should be any construct that will hold the child components of the parent component.

I expect that you will find, either a ComponentCount, or Components list or a FindComponent method in the parent object. 
Assuming that the "Self" referenced object is a Tform.

```
 for i := 0 to tForm(self).ComponentCount -1 do 
   if tForm(self).Components[i] is tPanel then 
      tPanel(tForm(self).Components[i]).Caption := intToStr(i) ;
```

will change all Captions of tPanels in your application. 
In order to distinguish between Panels created by code and designer you can use the TAG property of each created tPanel and use it in the above example.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've been using the tags to keep the panels "in order" by assigning sequential numbers to them based on the data table their characteristics is stored in.  Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the components you need references to a TList|Container... and then, use your list|container to access them

```
var
  slPanels: TStringList;
...


 With TypeQuery do begin // Create Panels
   First;
   While (not eof) do begin        // create the actual panel
      panelno := FieldByName('Product_type_id').AsInteger;
      pnl := Tpanel.Create(Self);
      pnl.name := FieldByName('PanelName').AsString;
      slPanels.AddObject(FieldByName('PanelName').AsString, pnl);
```

when you need it:

```
TPanel(slPanels.Objects[slPanels.IndexOf(FieldByName('PanelName').AsString)]) ...
```

I dislike the code above (there are better container... but this should do the job :o))

Comment: Why does everyone insist on creating a separate list? The form already has one (in the Components array), maybe two (the Controls array), the parent has one or two (in the Components and Controls arrays). You don't need yet another one. If you need a way to group them, use a naming convention or set a value to the `Tag` property.

Comment: maybe because I can access it with string instead of integer? ;o)

Comment: Sure... your way to do it, saves memory... (have you influence delphi R&D to implement the TagString property with FMX? ;o)))

Comment: @Ken, a container dedicated to storing just one kind of control can make things easier. For example, the numeric index of an item won't change just because you redesign the form. A string index isn't necessarily limited to what Delphi considers a valid identifier, and it doesn't have the same uniqueness constraints. You could even use other index types, like a database key. A dedicated container can also give faster access since it excludes all the uninteresting objects. Also, a separate list allows excluding the parent or owner for algorithms where it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Rob: My comment was based on the answer to *every single post* of this nature lately has been "create yet another list". I agree that it can make things easier sometimes, but it's not the automatic answer to the question of how to deal with controls created at runtime. In this case, there would be zero benefit in doing so. `FindControl(FieldValue)` would be just as good, and it avoids having to maintain another list. When there are several existing lists, there has to be a viable reason for creating yet another one. :-)

Comment: I ended up using an array for this and just kept track of the array index.   Thanks!